# Installed Ale linter using Pathogen, but none of the commands are working

Tags: plugin-ale, plugin-pathogen

I followed the [documentation for installing Ale using Pathogen](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale#3ii-installation-with-pathogen) but when I open a Vim file and type `:help ale-fix` or `:ALEFix` I get `E149: Sorry, no help for ale-fix` and `E492: Not an editor command: ALEFix`. Does anyone know what the reason might be?

I've used Pathogen before to install NERDTree the same way and am using that plugin fine.

Comment: Have you tried cloning the Ale repository to the same directory as NERDTree? You may have just cloned it somewhere else by mistake.

Comment: The Ale repository is in `~/.vim/bundle/` along with the NERDTree repository. I'm not sure if this is  the issue, but the current Vim that I'm using is 7.4 (2013 Aug 10) but the installation guide does say that it's for Vim 8. I'm also not sure if this is relevant to my issue, but I've noticed in this [GitHub Issue for Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/issues/486) that two .vimrc files may be a problem?

Comment: Please share more details, such as relevant snippets in your bike that enable Pathogen, the exact commands you used, etc. You can also look at `:set runtimepath?` to see if the Ale directory is included in the list, and `:scriptnames` to look at all scripts getting loaded during startup...

Comment: Oh yeah Ale requires Vim 8... If you type `:messages` you'll see the error message

Comment: Ah I see I didn't know that that was an absolute requirement... I'll have to ask my administrator to update Vim then. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ALE plug-in [requires](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/blob/c36053d4cc28fbc5fc0ee70ccb2c9a1b349eaaa3/plugin/ale.vim#L27) Vim 8 or NeoVim 0.2.0+.

If you open a file in the Vim command-line with Ale loaded (`vim /path/to/file.py` or similar), it will produce an error like the one below:

```
ALE requires NeoVim >= 0.2.0 or Vim 8 with +timers +job +channel
```

I suggest you install a more recent version of Vim or NeoVim to get Ale to work.

You might also want to consider using a more user-friendly and higher-level plug-in manager, such as [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug), which can install and update plug-ins for you and make it pretty obvious which ones are installed and available.